Prove $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f'(x)}{2x}}$ WITHOUT L'Hospital or Taylor series
Given that $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)$ is continuous, $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f'(x)}{x}=1}$, I want to show that
$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f(x)}{x^2}} = \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f'(x)}{2x}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
WITHOUT using L'Hospital or Taylor series. I cannot find the right way however I try.
==Edit: My Attempt==
Since $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{f'(x)}{x}=1}$, $f'(x) = x+q(x)$ where $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{q(x)}{x}} =0$
$f(x) =\int{f'(x)dx}=\int{x+q(x)dx}= \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \int{q(x)}dx$
Therefore I need to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\int{q(x)dx}}{x^2}}=0$
This is where I found myself stuck.

Show your efforts soon, as you got two downvotes by now.

You can re-prove as if you would prove l'Hospital.

It's incorrect to write $f(x)=\int f'(x) dx$. We have $f(x) =\int f'(x)dx \color{red} {+C}$, so it's not a good idea to use an indefinite integral. Try finding a particular antiderivative using a definite integral.

Define $g(x)=f(x)-\frac12x^2$ and try to combine properties of $g$ with simple arguments around the mean value theorem.

Your method works with definite integrals. Using $f(0)=0$ we have $f(x)=\int_0^x f’(t)dt=\tfrac{x^2}{2}+\int_0^xq(t)dt.$ Need to show $\tfrac{1}{x^2}\int_0^xq(t)dt\to 0$ as $x\to0.$ Now $\tfrac{1}{x^2}\int_0^xq(t)dt = \tfrac{1}{x}q(c_x)$ for some $0<c_x<x$ by the mean value theorem for integrals. But
$$\left| \frac{q(c_x)}{x} \right|
= \left| \frac{q(c_x)}{c_x}\right| \left| \frac{c_x}{x}\right| \leq \left| \frac{q(c_x)}{c_x}\right| \to 0 \text{ as }x\to 0.$$
To elaborate on the convergence. Since $\frac{q(x)}{x}\to0$ as $x\to0$, there is a $\delta>0$ is such that $0<t<\delta\implies \left| \frac{q(t)}{t}\right|<\varepsilon.$ So since $0<c_x<x$ we have  $0<x<\delta\implies0<c_x<\delta\implies \left| \frac{q(c_x)}{c_x}\right|<\varepsilon.  $

You don't need the MVT. Directly (with your notations):$$0<x<\delta\implies\left|\int_0^xq(t)dt\right|\le\int_0^x\varepsilon tdt=\varepsilon\frac{x^2}2.$$
